# How to retrieve menu item id if the url rewriting is enabled in joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0

Can anyone let me know that if the url rewriting is enabled in joomla and the url getting generated are seo friendly url's then in this case can I get menu item id if yes then what are the steps to get it.

for example my seo friendly url is www.example.com/store

I want to get menu item id from this url.

Answer (score 4):

To get all variable

```
 $Itemid = JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
```

To get the active menu

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;
echo $menu;
```

Answer (score 3):

`JRequest` is depricated in `Joomla 3`.
So you should use the following instead:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$Itemid = $jinput->getInt('Itemid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method:
    $menu =& JSite::getMenu();
    $Itemid = $menu->getActive()->id;